# CentOS > 日本語環境でmanだけ英語で読みたい

Tags: linux, centos, man

CentOS 6.5を使用しています。

テキストに漢字を使いたいため、以下のサイトを参考に日本語環境としました。
http://kwski.net/linux/208/

この変更の後、man lsなどでmanualを見ると日本語表記になっていました。

manのコマンドだけ英語表記にしたいと思い`LANG=C man ls`と実行してみましたが、日本語だった部分が文字化け(?となる)するだけで英語のmanualにはなりませんでした。

どのようにすれば日本語環境においてmanコマンドの出力を英語表示にすることができるでしょうか?

---

(追記)
yum info man-pages.noarchの結果です。

```
# yum info man-pages.noarch
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * centosplus: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
Installed Packages
Name        : man-pages
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 3.22
Release     : 20.el6
Size        : 4.3 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : anaconda-CentOS-201311272149.x86_64
Summary     : Man (manual) pages from the Linux Documentation Project
URL         : http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/manpages/
License     : GPLv2+ and GPL+ and BSD and MIT and Copyright only and IEEE
Description : A large collection of man pages (documentation) from the Linux
            : Documentation Project (LDP).
```

---

(追記) echo $MANPATHの結果です。
`/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/ja_JP:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/ja_JP:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man/ja:/usr/share/man/overrides:/usr/share/man::`

---

(追記) `locale -a | grep "ja\|en\|No"`の結果です。

`en_AG,en_AG.utf8,en_AU,en_AU.iso88591,en_AU.utf8,en_BW,en_BW.iso88591,en_BW.utf8,en_CA,en_CA.iso88591,en_CA.utf8,en_DK,en_DK.iso88591,en_DK.utf8,en_GB,en_GB.iso88591,en_GB.iso885915,en_GB.utf8,en_HK,en_HK.iso88591,en_HK.utf8,en_IE,en_IE.iso88591,en_IE.iso885915@euro,en_IE.utf8,en_IE@euro,en_IN,en_IN.utf8,en_NG,en_NG.utf8,en_NZ,en_NZ.iso88591,en_NZ.utf8,en_PH,en_PH.iso88591,en_PH.utf8,en_SG,en_SG.iso88591,en_SG.utf8,en_US,en_US.iso88591,en_US.iso885915,en_US.utf8,en_ZA,en_ZA.iso88591,en_ZA.utf8,en_ZW,en_ZW.iso88591,en_ZW.utf8,french,ja_JP,ja_JP.eucjp,ja_JP.ujis,ja_JP.utf8,japanese,japanese.euc,slovene,slovenian`

Comment: これは頑固な man ですね...　`locale -a | grep "ja\|en\|No"`の結果もあるといいかも。

Comment: man-pages-jaが不要なら、単に`yum remove man-pages-ja`でも良い気がしましたが、どうでしょうか。

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 解決しましたが、解決前の結果を掲載しました。私の頭と同じくらい堅物のmanでした。

Comment: @3100 `yum remove man-pages-ja`も試して再起動したのですが、文字化けは解消しませんでしたが、heliac2001さんとのやりとりで解決にいたりました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。多分後から見た人のためになると思います。ちょっと長いので短く編集しますね。

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto `tr "\n" ","`で行を圧縮しました。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

man コマンドの `--locale` オプションか `-L` オプションを使うと英語版(locale:C)のオンラインマニュアルを表示させることができます。

```
$ man -L C man
```

もしくは、`MANOPT` 環境変数に `-L C` をセットします。

```
$ export MANOPT="-L C"
$ man man
```

追記:

上記は Ubuntu Linux の場合(man version 2.6.7.1)でした。CentOS の場合は、

```
$ LC_ALL=C man man
```

とします。

さらに追記:

`MANPATH` の設定ですが、具体的には以下の様にしてみて下さい。

```
$ export MANPATH="/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.3.174/man/en_US:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man"
```

確認後、~/.bashrc か ~/.bash_profile に追記(もしくは変更)をお願いします。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
--localeや-Lをつけたところ「オプションが違います」となります。CentOSのmanはversion 1.6fですが、オプションが違うのでしょうか?

Comment: すみません、こちらの環境は Ubuntu Linux で、man は 2.6.7.1 です。CentOS の場合について調べてみます。

Comment: export MANOPT="-L C"も試しましたが、こちらは日本語が文字化けせず表示されるだけで英語とはなりませんでした。

Comment: お手数おかけいたします。`LC_ALL=C man man`を試してみましたが、日本語部分が文字化けして表示されました。

Comment: 「yum info man-pages.noarch」を実行するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: `$ sudo yum install man-pages-ja` ですかね？

Comment: 了解です。それでは「LC_MESSAGES= man man」としてみていただけますか？

Comment: こちらの CentOS 6.5 では英語版・日本語版マニュアルがインストールされているのですが、「LC_ALL=C man 〜」で英語版が表示されますね。。。

Comment: @heliac2001 yum info man-pages.noarchの結果を質問の追記として追加しました。

Comment: @ohga yum install man-pages-jaをしてみましたが日本語表記のままとなります。

Comment: @heliac2001 `LC_MESSAGES=C man man`と`LC_ALL=C man man`ともに日本語部分が文字化けとなります。 漢字入力のための設定変更で何か間違いをしてしまったのかもしれません。あと、ターミナルはgnome-terminalですが、関係あるのでしょうか?

Comment: @sevenOfNine ごめんなさい install じゃなくて remove でしたが、そもそも乱暴すぎな気がしてきました。。

Comment: @sevenOfNine 何もしなければ日本語マニュアルはきちんと表示されていますのでターミナルの問題とは考えづらいですね。。。

Comment: @sevenOfNine たびたびすみません、「echo $MANPATH」を実行してその結果を教えていただけますか？

Comment: @heliac2001 質問に追記しました。

Comment: 分かりました。MANPATH から "*/ja" や "*/ja_JP"となっているパスを全て取り除いて再設定していただけますか？

Comment: @heliac2001 `export MANPATH=/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man`とした後で`LANG=C man man`とすると英語表記となりました。ありがとうございます！！！

Comment: @heliac2001 追記いただいたMANPATHの設定できちんと動作しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

MANPATH に /usr/share/man/ja が入っているため、LANG を変更しても /usr/share/man/ja/ 以下のファイルが先に見つかってしまうのだと思います。

Comment: LANGは知っていたのですが、MANPATHは理解していませんでした。